# Copy to USB is very slow

Tags: usb, copy, gvfs

Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS from 32 bit machines to a USB stick or winchester, the speed is approx. starting at 25MB/s, it slows down to 100kB/s. At the end of the copying, you will stand for a long time. A ca. Copy the 1.5GB file to approx. it lasts for 20 minutes: unusable ...
Ports and Devices: USB2 and USB3.

```
4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:22 UTC 2017
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS from 32 bit machines to a USB stick or winchester, the speed is approx. starting at 25MB/s, it slows down to 100kB/s. At the end of the copying, you will stand for a long time. A ca. Copy the 1.5GB file to approx. it lasts for 20 minutes: unusable ...
Ports and Devices: USB2 and USB3.

4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:22 UTC 2017
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
My machine has 16GB of memory.

Values from the sysctl file:
/.../
vm.admin_reserve_kbytes = 8192
vm.block_dump = 0
vm.compact_unevictable_allowed = 1
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.dirtytime_expire_seconds = 43200
vm.drop_caches = 0
vm.extfrag_threshold = 500
vm.highmem_is_dirtyable = 0
vm.hugepages_treat_as_movable = 0
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0
vm.laptop_mode = 0
vm.legacy_va_layout = 0
vm.lowmem_reserve_ratio = 256 32 32
vm.max_map_count = 65530
vm.min_free_kbytes = 34096
vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
sysctl: permission denied on key 'vm.mmap_rnd_bits'
vm.nr_hugepages = 0
vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
vm.nr_pdflush_threads = 0
vm.oom_dump_tasks = 1
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 0
vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
vm.page-cluster = 3
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
vm.percpu_pagelist_fraction = 0
vm.stat_interval = 1
sysctl: permission denied on key 'vm.stat_refresh'
vm.swappiness = 60
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 131072
vm.vdso_enabled = 1
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100
vm.watermark_scale_factor = 10
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDLW9.png

Comment: What file system on the USB ? This is sort of a long standing issue and if you search launchpad there are many bug reports. https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/+bugs?field.searchtext=copy+slow+usb&search=Search+Bug+Reports&field.scope=all&field.scope.target=

Comment: And what kind of usb drive is it? I bought a **new** Kingston 8GB USB**3** stick a few months back. Write speed? 5MB/S... They vary a lot in quality.

Comment: - The pendrive new USB3 SanDiskUltra...

Comment: To Panther:  Thanks for editing this question ...